# Insert an object at a specific position in NSOrderedSet in CoreData?

Tags: core-data, nsorderedset

Setting up a "To Many" relationship in CoreData and ticking the "Ordered" box defines your attribute as a NSOrderedSet.

Is there an efficient way to insert an object at a specific position or to move an object up and down?

Or do I need to create a NSMutabledOrderedSet with the data from the NSOrderedSet, insert or move my objects and then convert it back to NSOrderedSet?

Or should I use a standard NSSet and manage a 'position' attribute myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoreData 'Create NSManagedObject Subclasses...' will generate a lot of methods for you to use to manipulate your ordered set. Or you can do the same with Codegen.

Objective C

```
@interface MyObject (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)insertObject:(NSManagedObject *)value inItemsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;
- (void)removeObjectFromItemsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;
- (void)insertItems:(NSArray<NSManagedObject *> *)value atIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes;
- (void)removeItemsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes;
- (void)replaceObjectInItemsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx withObject:(NSManagedObject *)value;
- (void)replaceItemsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes withItems:(NSArray<NSManagedObject *> *)values;
- (void)addItemsObject:(NSManagedObject *)value;
- (void)removeItemsObject:(NSManagedObject *)value;
- (void)addItems:(NSOrderedSet<NSManagedObject *> *)values;
- (void)removeItems:(NSOrderedSet<NSManagedObject *> *)values;

@end
```

Swift

```
// MARK: Generated accessors for items
extension MyObject {

    @objc(insertObject:inItemsAtIndex:)
    @NSManaged public func insertIntoItems(_ value: NSManagedObject, at idx: Int)

    @objc(removeObjectFromItemsAtIndex:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromItems(at idx: Int)

    @objc(insertItems:atIndexes:)
    @NSManaged public func insertIntoItems(_ values: [NSManagedObject], at indexes: NSIndexSet)

    @objc(removeItemsAtIndexes:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromItems(at indexes: NSIndexSet)

    @objc(replaceObjectInItemsAtIndex:withObject:)
    @NSManaged public func replaceItems(at idx: Int, with value: NSManagedObject)

    @objc(replaceItemsAtIndexes:withItems:)
    @NSManaged public func replaceItems(at indexes: NSIndexSet, with values: [NSManagedObject])

    @objc(addItemsObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToItems(_ value: NSManagedObject)

    @objc(removeItemsObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromItems(_ value: NSManagedObject)

    @objc(addItems:)
    @NSManaged public func addToItems(_ values: NSOrderedSet)

    @objc(removeItems:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromItems(_ values: NSOrderedSet)

}
```

Otherwise yes just make a mutable copy, manipulate as necessary, then set it back into the NSManagedObject. btw, you don't need to convert it back to a non-mutable set either

Comment: Could you please clarify where are those methods generated? They don't seem to be available for my attribute. I am using Swift and the attribute is declared as follows:  
`code`@NSManaged var elements: NSOrderedSet?
if I start typing the following it doesn't auto-complete:
    elements.insert

Comment: They will be named differently in swift, core data will generate YourClass+CoreDataProperties.swift they will be in there

Comment: The Class+CoreDataProperties.swift that has been generated has only attributes. There are no methods. I am using iOS btw.

Comment: I have just done this in a new swift project and added the swift version of the methods generated to my answer.

Comment: Thanks @trapper, I updated to Xcode 8 and I can now see the extensions. They were not created with Xcode 7.3

Comment: Don't make a mutable copy, use `mutableOrderedSetValueForKey`.

Comment: Nice one Willeke, I never noticed that before!

Comment: I've been having a similar issue with a slight difference:  I can not INSERT anything into my NSOrderedSet.  All of the insert functions auto generated simply append the object to the end of my ordered set.  Likewise, the replace functions do not work either, they also just append the new object to the end of the ordered set, leaving the object at the specified index in place.

I have a new question I added here with more details if anyone has any ideas:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43375412/insert-object-at-an-index-is-not-working-for-nsmanagedobject-nsorderedset